# Проблема с обработкой форм PHP

Tags: php, html

Создал скрипт который должен реагировать на нажатие кнопки (с произвольным именем из 1 символа), однако при выполнении ничего не происходит и возвращается ошибка:

> Notice: Undefined index: name in /var/ex/index.php on line 5.

Код:

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <p><button type="submit" name="1" class="btn">1</button></p>
</form>
```

```
<?php
if ( isset ( $_POST[((preg_match('(.)',$_POST['name'])))] ) )
    {
        echo 'Кнопка нажата!';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Опишите еще раз задачу в целом. Скорее всего вы немного не тот инструмент используете. Отследить нажатие одной из множества кнопок куда легче на JavaScript в самой форме, чем на сервере уже обрабатывая пришедшую форму. Если все кнопки с `type=submit` лежат в одной форме - они все придут на сервер в $_POST, и вы не сможете понять - какую именно нажал пользователь из них. Альтернатива - можно сделать для каждой кнопки свою форму, и отслеживать нажатую как вы это сделали сейчас, по имени кнопки. Но тогда сделайте для каждой кнопки свою форму (изолированную от других)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Давать название кнопкам лучше логическое, так как у вас может быть 10 кнопок+модальные окна и прочее.. Например:

```html
<button type="submit" name="testClick" class="btn">Проверка нажатия</button>
```

2. Вы кнопке объявили `name="1"`, а на сервере проверяете приход неведомой кнопки или поля `$_POST['name']`!
3. Это вообще сказка)

   ```
   if ( isset ( $_POST[((preg_match('(.)',$_POST['name'])))] ) )
   ```

   > Error: There is 1 predefined variables that should be treated as an ['array']:

Если вы так будите проверять 20 полей, то вскоре сами запутаетесь что делаете.
Универсальная проверка:

```
if ( isset ( $_POST['testClick'] ) ) {
    # do something, for example:
    echo 'Ура! Кнопка нажата!';
}
```

> UPD решение вашей задачи (сохраните как `index.php`):

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

if ( isset ( $_POST['testClick'] ) ) {
    # do something, for example:
    echo 'Ура! Кнопка нажата!';
    echo $_POST['testClick'];

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="testClick" class="btn" value="1"> Кнопка 1</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Если вам надо много кнопок, то каждой кнопке вешаем класс и пишем скрипт который меняет значение кнопки в форме:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.check', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('button[name="testClick"]').val( $(this).val() );
});
```

```html
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

if ( isset ( $_POST['testClick'] ) ) {
    # do something, for example:
    echo 'Ура! Кнопка нажата!';
    echo $_POST['testClick'];

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <button type="submit" name="check1" class="btn check" value="1"> Кнопка 1</button>
    <button type="submit" name="check2" class="btn check" value="2"> Кнопка 2</button>
    <button type="submit" name="check3" class="btn check" value="3"> Кнопка 3</button>
    <button type="submit" name="check4" class="btn check" value="4"> Кнопка 4</button>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="testClick" class="btn" value=""> Кнопка 1</button>
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Дело в том что есть n кнопок и при нажатии каждой из них нужно выполнять одинаковое действие из за этого обрабатывать каждую несколько проблематично. Потому и использую регулярные выражения. Идея в том что кнопка будет передавать имя типа "button_n" и потом с ним будут работать, а вверху слегка упрощённая версия

Comment: @Никита сейчас подправлю ответ. Если это решит вашу задачу, примите ответ.

Comment: @Никита подправил ещё.

Answer (score -1):

Имя у вашего button -> "1" а вы пытаетесь его получить как "name", value вообще не указан

и лучше уж использовать  чем пытаться получить value из button